# Multidimensional regression with keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, regression, prediction

I want to predict an x, y coordinate based on n inputs using keras. I am unclear why my network won't improve after about 5 epochs. I don't understand why the network values such as x=2.9 and y=2.1 if my input variables vary from 5-14(x) and 5-11(y). How can i get better predictions?

Data:

```
input:
[[-92.    0.  -83.    0.    0.    0. ]
[  0.    0.    0.  -82.    0.    0. ]
...
[-65.5 -82.    0.    0.    0.    0. ]]
output:
[[ 5  5]
[ 5  5]
...
[11 14]]
Results:
Predicted:  [4.396636 4.019871]  label:  [11 14]  Difference:  16.583492755889893
Predicted:  [2.9728146 2.1784768]  label:  [11 14]  Difference:  19.848708629608154
Predicted:  [3.9281645 4.2113876]  label:  [11 14]  Difference:  16.860447883605957
```

Network:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import *

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim = ipad_test_numpy_input.shape[1], activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(ipad_numpy_input, ipad_numpy_labels, epochs=50, batch_size=5)
score = model.evaluate(ipad_test_numpy_input, ipad_test_numpy_labels, batch_size=5)
```

Comment: On top of the answer below, you need to *normalise* your data before feeding them into a neural network...

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the activation on your first two layers to

```
activation='relu'
```

and see if that improves things at all by introducing non-linearity. You're currently just performing a series of linear transformations, so you're not really leveraging the power of a neural net in any way. There are a lot of other reasons why things might not be working as well as you hope, but they are a bit beyond the scope of a stackoverflow answer. If you have a big enough dataset, then regularization would be a good first thing to start reading up on though.

Comment: thx for your reply. I changed the initial layers to relu but am receiving even worse results. I did split into ipad_TEST and ipad_ data. I will look into regularization.

Comment: So now I experimented around adding Batch_normalization to the first layer and shuffling. Then I made a grid search with batch_size, epochs, learning_rate, momentum, dropout, momentum, kernel regularizer (l1 and l2), neurons per layer, number of layers, activation function, initialization and relation of neurons from one layer to the next. 

After all this, I made progress, yet have quite insufficient results (2-3m acccuracy in a 9x9m room), what could I do?

Comment: How big is your dataset?

Comment: 3864 entries. Would you recommend more? My gridsearch resulted that these parameters were the best until now:
`neurons=550, optimizer='adam', activation='relu', learn_rate=0.001, momentum=0.004, init_mode='he_uniform', dropout_rate=0.0, n_of_layers=3, neuron_shrink_rate=0.5, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0) `

Comment: It depends a bit on the problem, but that's really around or below the lower limit for using a deep learning architecture. If you're able to easily get a lot more data it would probably help: samples_min = parameters^2 is a very rough rule of thumb...by that calc you'd need at least 300,000 samples for your 550 neuron network (you probably have way more than 550 parameters though).  I'd probably prefer different methods tbh (e.g. do you have a baseline with vanilla least squares?).